# How to embed gnome-terminal window inside of a QT QMainWindow? (QT5 / C++ / RHEL 8)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, rhel, gnome-terminal

I've been trying to embed a gnome-terminal window inside of a QT QMainWindow and I've been testing out my code so far with a hard coded window ID that I grab through xwininfo, and when I run my application the gnome-terminal window does get embedded into the QT MainWindow but it is either a frozen screen or a completely blank black screen.

I don't know what to change about my code because when I try it out with other applications (like wireshark for example) it ends up embedding perfectly inside of the QMainWindow and is not frozen at all. Until I set a fixed height and width the terminal would open up very small while wireshark would open up at a normal size.

Would appreciate any help since I haven't been working with QT for that long! I've attached some code and some screenshots below.

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow;
    w->setWindowTitle("Terminal on QT");
    QWindow *window = QWindow::fromWinId(0x3e0174a);

    if(window == nullptr){
        qDebug() << "it is a null pointer";
    }

    window->setFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    QWidget *widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(window);
    widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NativeWindow, true); // This didn't really make any difference
    w->setCentralWidget(widget);
    w->setFixedHeight(502);   
    w->setFixedWidth(735);
    w->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[running application with wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUsJa.png)

[running application with gnome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YehNn.png)

[xwininfo for gnome-terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlN87.png)

[xwininfo for wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URkkh.png)

Comment: If you just want a terminal in your application, why not just use KDE's KonsolePart? Its cross platform and will integerate natively as its written in qt.

Comment: There's also [qtermwidget](https://github.com/lxqt/qtermwidget), if you don't want to pull in the whole KDE Frameworks infrastructure for KonsolePart...